# Transforming data in Excel/Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I have just started learning about Power Query. Hopefully, I have come to the right place :)

I am working with data on the parts structure of a complex machine. It is comprised of several 'assembly levels'. The data looks like this

[image]

The cell values represent part codes. Level 6 is assembled into level 5, which is assembled into level 4 etc. An example with the sample data would be: level 6 part codes 10 & 11 are assembled into level 5 part code 9, which, along with level 5 part code 12, is assembled into level 4 part code 8 etc. Level 1 represents the end product.

In order to set up an analysis of pre-sale expected costs vs actual costs I want to transform the data only to include rows with the lowest assembly level for each part, like this:

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to do this in Power Query and/or Excel.

I tried filling down the level 2 column, followed by deleting all rows for which the level 3 - level 6 columns are empty in order to remove rows that do not show the lowest assembly level of a part—after that, repeating this for every subsequent column. This does not work because, in the end, I have deleted all rows where the part is not on the lowest assembly level (6 in this case).

Answer (score 3):

No easy feat, this is my two cents:

[image]

```
=LET(q,REDUCE({0,0,0,0,0},B2:B21,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TOROW(N(OFFSET(y,ROW(1:5)-1,ROW(1:5)-1)))))),f,FILTER(q,MMULT(q,{1;1;1;1;1})),VSTACK(A1:F1,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(f),6,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c=1,1,LET(v,INDEX(f,r,c-1),rw,DROP(CHOOSEROWS(f,r),,c-2),cl,TAKE(CHOOSECOLS(f,c-1),r),IF(v,v,IF(ISERR(@FILTER(rw,rw)),"",TAKE(FILTER(cl,cl),-1)))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution. If I try this on my dataset I get a #CALC! error saying the problem is an Empty Array.

Answer (score 3):

My half-cent powerquery abomination, agnostic to number of levels / columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
columns=Table.ColumnNames(Source),
columnnumbers=List.Count(columns),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,null,"+",Replacer.ReplaceValue,columns),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
shiftedList = List.Repeat({"+"},columnnumbers) & List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(#"Unpivoted Other Columns","Value"),columnnumbers),
shiftedList2 = List.Repeat({"+"},1) & List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(#"Unpivoted Other Columns","Value"),1),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns") & {shiftedList}& {shiftedList2},
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Unpivoted Other Columns") & {"shift1","shift2"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(custom2, "Custom", each if [Value]="+" and [shift1]<>"+" and [shift2]<>"+" and [Attribute]<>columns{1} then "]" else [Value]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value", "shift1", "shift2"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each ([Custom] <> "+")),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Custom"),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Pivoted Column",columns),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled Down",List.Transform(columns,each {_, type text})),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Index"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns2",null,"]",Replacer.ReplaceValue,columns),
#"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1","]",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,columns),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value2", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(_)),",")),
shiftedList3 = List.RemoveFirstN(  #"Added Custom1"[Custom],1),
custom3 = Table.ToColumns( #"Added Custom1") & {shiftedList3},
custom4 = Table.FromColumns(custom3,Table.ColumnNames( #"Added Custom1") & {"Shift"}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(custom4, "Custom2", each Text.Contains([Shift],[Custom])),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom2", each ([Custom2] <> true)),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{ "Custom", "Shift", "Custom2"})
in #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution. This does work on the example data, however it does not work on my real dataset (6 columns and 1100 rows). For some rows I end up with for example the cell in column 3 being empty while cells in columns 1, 2 and 4 do have a value.

Comment: If you don't provide a real data set with proposed solution, I'm not sure I would be able to troubleshoot. Sorry